# Should I use .gitignore, or auto-detect configurations for different servers in staging?

Tags: git, cakephp, configuration

I am working in a firm where we currently do not have any staging workflow, and things are getting tight. I am trying to set up a proper workflow and have read some excellent tutorials and resources for different approaches. The workflow that I will be using is that developers commit and push their codes to a dev repo, which is then copied to prod repo. Then a simple pull is done on the prod server.

We are using CakePHP. There are 2 servers (prod and dev) and of course the localhost. However, the configurations (db, payments, auth etc) are different for each environment. My main question is that which option is better from the below (other suggestions are also welcomed)?

### OPTION 1:

- Set up all 3 environments with their appropriate configs
- Use the .gitignore to ignore configs and env-specific files
- Use simple push/pull

### OPTION 2:

- Use PHP mechanisms to detect the environment and select appropriate configuration
- No need to use .gitignore (other than may be just ignoring the tmp files etc)
- Use simple push/pull

I would like to know whats the best way to do this. Also, a recommendation for a Git workflow with easy deployment would be great.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the kind of thing your `.gitignore` file is for, go with option 1.

Comment: So you suggest that .gitignore should be used for all configuration files, but what if I have quite a few inline configurations in the main application code? Such as I need to do a particular computation based on the environment and say I have several of these cases which are hard to abstract in a config file. I don't know if I explained it clear enough :S

Comment: Ideally you'd abstract that sort of thing out so your code stays the same in all places. You could use the config file to choose an implementation of an initialization function for instance.